# Finding $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^n f(1+\frac{x}{n^2})g(x)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Given $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable and $f：\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, measurable, and continuous at $1$. Find
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^n f\left(1+\frac{x}{n^2}\right)g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

I was thinking of using dominated convergence, but I can't find a dominator…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\int_{-n}^n f\left(1+\frac{x}{n^2}\right)g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x= \int_{\mathbb R} 1_{(-n,n)} f\left(1+\frac{x}{n^2}\right)g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Now let $f_n(x):=1_{(-n,n)} f\left(1+\frac{x}{n^2}\right)g(x)$.

If $x \in \mathbb R$, then there is $N$ such that $x \in (-n,n)$ for all $n>N$, hence

$f_n(x) = f\left(1+\frac{x}{n^2}\right)g(x)$ for all $n>N$,thus

$f_n(x) \to f(1)g(x)$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Thanks :) That's very clear and $f(1)g(x)$ is integrable because $g$ is. I'm just not sure if the final limit is $f(1)\int g\, dx$ or I can continue.

Comment: There is $c \ge 0$ such that $|f(x)| \le c$ for all $ x \in \mathbb R$, hence we have $|f_n| \le c|g|$ on $ \mathbb R$. Since $g$ is integrable, $|g|$ is integrable. Using dominated convergence, we can deduce: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^n f\left(1+\frac{x}{n^2}\right)g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb R} f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=f(1)\int_{\mathbb R} g\, dx.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be a bound of $f$ and consider $M\,|g|$.

Comment: thanks! but how can I find the limit of $f(1)g(x)$

Comment: $f(1)\,g(x)$ is the limit of the integrand as $n\to\infty$.